# Looking for a magnifyer function

Tags: special-functions

I am looking for a function $f$ having the following characteristics:

- $f$ defined on $[0,1]$
- $f(0)=0$
- $f(1)=1$
- $ \forall x \in ]0,1[, x <f(x) < 1$
- $f$ differentiable on $]0,1]$
- $f'>0$
- $f'(1)=1$
- $\lim\limits_{x\to0} f'(x)=+\infty$

Finally, I will also need an analytical expression of the inverse function $f^{-1}$.

Do you know such function?

Comment: is that last requirement really $xf(x) \rightarrow 1 $ for $x\rightarrow 0$? Are you requiring continuity of $F$ at $x=0$?

Comment: @Thomas yes, my last requirement is what you have written. And, f has to be continuous on [0,1]

Comment: Your requirements are incompatible. Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, and $f(0)=0$. Then as $x$ approaches $0$, $f(x)$ approaches $0$. Thus $xf(x)$ cannot approach $1$.  But that's what your last condition requires. Maybe modify the requirements, possibly by removing the last one. Or did you mean that the **ratio** $x/f(x)$ must approach $1$?

Comment: oops, I did a mistake in my last requirement: it is $x f'(x)$ and not $x f(x)$. Sorry.

Comment: @julien: The altered condition that $\lim_{x\to 0} xf'(x)=1$ is still incompatible with the others, though more work is needed to show the incompatibility. You are asking for the derivative to behave like $1/x$ near $0$. That's too high a rate of blowup.

Comment: Thanks andré, you are right: the last condition is incompatible. I replace it with: $\lim\limits_{x\to0} f'(x)=+\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is the function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ defined by
$$
f(x)=\tfrac12(1+x)\sqrt{x},
$$
whose inverse function $g$ is defined by
$$
g(y)=\left(\sqrt{y^2+\tfrac1{27}}+y\right)^{2/3}+\left(\sqrt{y^2+\tfrac1{27}}-y\right)^{2/3}-\tfrac23
$$

Comment: Thanks Didier. Are you sure the inverse function is correct?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Jewel-like example!